# Call save action on ItemEditForm from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe

I'm using Stripe.js to try and retrieve a token for a payment source before the ItemEdit form is submitted. I'm able to stop the form submission and grab the token, but I'm trying to figure out how to call the submit action again after the AJAX request is completed (successfully). Right now I'm using `form.submit()`, but that wants to refresh the entire page and gives me an ugly alert (Leave/Stay). Is anyone aware of a smoother way to do this?

```
(function($) {
    $.entwine('ss', function($) {
        var form = $('#Form_ItemEditForm');
        var field = $('input.stripetokenfield');

        $(form).entwine({
            onsubmit: function(e) {
                var key = getStripeFieldByData(form, 'key');
                var token_field = getStripeFieldByData(form, 'token');
                Stripe.setPublishableKey(key.val());
                Stripe.card.createToken(form, stripeResponseHandler);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    function getStripeFieldByData(form, string) {
        var field = $(form).find('[data-stripe="' + string + '"]');
        return field;
    }

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        var form = $('#Form_ItemEditForm');
        if(response.error) {
            form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        }else {
            var token_field = getStripeFieldByData(form, 'token');
            token_field.val(response.id);
            if(token_field.val()) {
                form.get(0).submit();
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make the request and avoid refreshing the page, this can likely be done by sending the form data with a jQuery POST.

```
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(response){
  // do something here on success
});
```

And if you wanted to refresh, you could manually do so on success with a `window.location.reload()` or redirect the user using `window.location.replace()` or `window.location.href` to a landing page.

Documentation: [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)